# How do I deserialize a JSON file using json4s without reading into a string first?

Tags: scala, json4s

I can read JSON from a file into a string and then deserialize like so:

```
val jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myObject.json")))
val json = parse(jsonString)
val myObject = json.extract[MyClass]
```

This seems inefficient to me, especially for large files, because I'm reading into a string first and only then passing the string to the deserializer.

Is it possible to deserialize directly from a file using json4s, or is the only way to read into memory first?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could: you don't know that a json message is well-formed until you have reached its end.

Comment: That's a good point but I'm not sure it's an impediment. If you encounter an unexpected token at some point you can always raise an exception.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more; even if the string is in memory parsing probably still works the same way (left to right) and you cannot determine if the JSON is well-formed without reading the string sequentially to the end. So I see no difference between parsing directly from disk vs. reading the entire string in memory first.

I'll probably dig through the source code a bit and see if it's possible to modify it easily to read directly from disk.